# Invalid parameter: Attributes Reason: Platform credentials are invalid

Tags: amazon-sns

I am working with AWS SNS Implementation in My iOS app and I followed all SNS documentation to create platform in SNS Dashboard.

I am getting an error like "Invalid parameter: Attributes Reason: Platform credentials are invalid " When creating new platform application and please anyone guide me to sort this issue.

Comment: And what have you done?

Comment: I have used the same .cer file, while I was generating the Development and Push Development certificates.
It is working fine when I used the different .cer files.

Answer (score 3):

Amazon SNS differentiates between the production (APNS) and development (APNS_SANDBOX) versions of apple's push notification services. The error you are encountering is typical to developers accidentally attempting to create an APNS platform application with APNS_SANDBOX credentials, or vice-versa. Can you confirm whether you are using the correct set of credentials for the given platform?

Regards,

-Sid

Answer (score 0):

For people who are configuring Apple Push Notification in AWS Mobile Hub, remember it now (since late 2015) has simplified the APNS certificate to take a single Universal (Production + Sandbox) certificate, so when you generate APNS certificate, remember to choose `Sandbox & Production`:

[image]

and upload the generated .p12 file to AWS.